# Neteller merchant api setup php

Tags: php

I want to setup the neteller merchant api in my website that my client can pay me.

anyone can give me a overall guideline? I search over the internet but cannot find the proper solution

thanks In advance

Comment: Can you give us more information about what you already tried? Stackoverflow will gladly help you with problems that might occur during the implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Are you going to integrate just wallet payments, or you want to integrate the NETELLERgo! payment gateway as well? The steps for both solutions are different.

Anyway, in general, first off you will have to setup your merchant account for use with the NETELLER REST API. The steps include:

1. Go to your merchant account >> "Developer" tab >> "Documentation" page and download the latest REST API Reference guide. You will need that a lot.
2. Set up the IP addresses from which your webserver will be accessing the NETELLER API. You can do it from your merchant account >> “Developer” tab >> ”API Settings” page. See the the REST API guide, page 18.
3. Create a new App. This step is necessary in order to get REST API access credentials. This can be done from your merchant account >> “Developer” tab >> ”Apps” page. See the REST API guide, page 19.

Now you are ready to use your merchant account for requests to the NETELLER REST API.

If you are going to integrate just **NETELLER wallet payments**, the rest of the steps would be:

1. Get access token. Your application will first need to obtain an access token in order to be able to make a request to a resource in the API. To do that, you will need the “client_id” and “client_secret” values, which were generated during Step 3) above. More details are available in the REST API guide, page 41. Please note that you will need to get a new token for each request you make to the API.
2. Create a deposit/withdrawal. Using a new token from Step 1) above, make a request to the REST API for an incoming/outgoing transfer. You will need to build a form, which collects the customer's payment credentials and passes them in the API request. More details are available in the REST API guide, pages 54 and 58.

This integration requires you to build the payments page - there is no redirection to the NETELLER gateway, just 2 API requests and the payment is done.

If you are going to integrate **NETELLERgo!**, follow these steps:

1. Get access token. (see above)
2. Create an order. Using a new token from Step 1) above, make a request to the REST API for a new order. More details are available in the REST API guide, page 63.
3. Redirect the user – In response to step 2) above, you will receive a link to a hosted payment page where you need to redirect the customer to complete the payment.
4. Implement webhooks – You will need to implement webhooks for payment events, which will handle confirmation of the transaction status. More details on webhooks are available in the REST API guide, page 108.

Comment: Sorry, I have downvoted your answer. Your answer itself is great and should be worth an upvote. But the question is outstandingly poor, and we don't want to encourage asking such bad questions by honoring them with great answers. Save your energy for someone who deserves it! :)